# Why do .CSV files downloaded as .TXT in postman?

Tags: csv, postman

I was verifying the HTTP content-type header and the file extensions via postman *(Using 'Send and Download' button with the HTTP GET request on file URLs)*.
We have different type of sample files available at http://www.sample-videos.com. and following are some results

- content-type **image/jpeg**   file downloaded as *response.jpg*
- content-type **audio/mpeg**   file downloaded as *response.mpg*
- content-type **application/vnd.ms-excel** file downloaded as *response.xls*
- content-type **application/vnd.ms-powerpoint** file downloaded as *sample.ppt*
- content-type **text/plain**  file downloaded as *response.txt*
- content-type **application/pdf** file downloaded as *sample.pdf*
- content-type **text/csv** file downloaded as *response.txt*

Can anyone please explain why the `text/csv` file is downloaded with extension `.txt` instead of `.csv`? Also see the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot from postman with the response headers and save dialog]

Comment: Is this issue resolved?? do you using s3 bucket for repository?

Comment: @gamechanger17 I've checked this again in Postman v7.11.0 - no issues, the file saved as csv. seems it was a bug on postman earlier.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default postman goes to when it doesn't fully understand the content-type.
You need to include 'charset=utf-8' in the content type, as in `text/csv; charset=utf-8`

Comment: No luck! I've added the screenshot. the response headers do  have the `content-type`.